# change database collation without changing column collation

Tags: sql-server-2008

i change the collation of my database from

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to

```
Persian_100_CI_AI
```

but i don't want to change my Previous **tables column** collation and they have

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation`  now .

is it correct solution or it will Cause problems?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the database collation doesn't affect any existing objects:

```
create database DB1
collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
go
use DB1
go
create table T1 (c varchar(20) not null)
go
alter database DB1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
go
select collation_name from sys.columns where name='c'
```

Result:

```
collation_name
---------------
Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

From [Set or Change the database collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175835.aspx):

> - You can change the collation of any new objects that are created in a user database by using the COLLATE clause of the ALTER DATABASE statement. This statement does not change the collation of the columns in any existing user-defined tables. These can be changed by using the COLLATE clause of ALTER TABLE.

Comment: thanks, i want to know if i dont change the collation of my previous tables, it cause problem ????

Comment: @shahnazfeiziamiri - if you leave the existing collation alone, then you'll tend to find that you frequently have to include a `COLLATE` clause in queries - SQL Server will force you to be explicit any time that the two collations are involved in a direct comparison.